# Задача в python

Tags: python

```
autoshop1 = {
'BMW': [5000],
'Kia': [6500],
'Lada': [2000],
'Ford': [3000],  
'Skoda': [4200],
'Audi': [6700],
'Honda': [2500],
'Mazda': [3600],
'Renault': [8800],
'Toyota': [5350]
 }
autoshop2 = autoshop1.copy() 
price_list = []
min_price = 0
for price_year_list in autoshop2.values():
      price_list.append(price_year_list[0])  
min_price = min(price_list)
for key_name_car, price_year_list in list(autoshop2.items()):
      if price_year_list[0] == min_price:
del autoshop2[key_name_car]  
else:
      price_year_list[0] = round(random.uniform(1000, 25500))  
autoshop2.update({'Volkswagen': [55555]})
print(autoshop2)`
```

Сделал все, никак не получается решить последний вопрос: реализует функцию, которая по введенной марке автомобиля выводит название магазина, в котором этот автомобиль дешевле и его цену в этом магазине.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса исправьте на что-нибудь более значимое

Comment: сделайте список автомагазинов и ищите в нем примерно, как минимальную цену

Comment: что вообще делает этот код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В оригинальном коде ничего не менял, кроме `copy` на `deepcopy` (иначе цены во всех магазинах на одинаковые марки всегда будут равны) - см. [поверхностное и глубокое копирование объектов](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-copy.html), а также отступов `del...else`.
Комментарии в коде.

```
import random
from copy import deepcopy

autoshop1 = {
    'BMW': [5000],
    'Kia': [6500],
    'Lada': [2000],
    'Ford': [3000],
    'Skoda': [4200],
    'Audi': [6700],
    'Honda': [2500],
    'Mazda': [3600],
    'Renault': [8800],
    'Toyota': [5350]
}
autoshop2 = deepcopy(autoshop1)
price_list = []
min_price = 0
for price_year_list in autoshop2.values():
    price_list.append(price_year_list[0])
min_price = min(price_list)
for key_name_car, price_year_list in list(autoshop2.items()):
    if price_year_list[0] == min_price:
        del autoshop2[key_name_car]
    else:
        price_year_list[0] = round(random.randint(1000, 25500))
autoshop2.update({'Volkswagen': [55555]})
print(autoshop2)

# новый код
shops = {'Железный конь': autoshop1, 'Эх, прокачу': autoshop2} # создаем словарь с магазинами, а не список, чтобы оперировать с названиями магазинов
marka = input('Введите марку: ')
min_price, min_shop = None, '' # задаем стартовые значения минимальной цены и дешевого магазина
for shop, models in shops.items(): #перебираем магазины
    # если марки нет в текущем магазине, переходим к следующему
    # если есть и цена не инициализирована (None), инициализируем первой попавшейся ценой на марку
    # если есть и цена инициализирована, сравниваем и, если она меньше, чем ранее, запоминаем цену и магазин 
    if marka in models and (min_price is None or models[marka][0] < min_price):
        min_price, min_shop = models[marka][0], shop
if min_price is not None: # если цена была инициализирована, то такая марка была найдена, выводим
    print(f'Автомобиль `{marka}` дешевле всего в `{min_shop}`: {min_price}')
else: # иначе сообщаем, что поиск неудачен
    print(f'Автомобиля `{marka}` нет ни в одном из магазинов: {"; ".join(shops.keys())}')
```